# What is $\int_X +\infty\ d\mu$ if $\mu(X) = 0$?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal S, \mu)$ be a measure space such that $\mu (X) = 0.$ Define a non-negative simple $\mathcal S$-measurable function $s  : X \longrightarrow [0,+\infty]$ as follows $:$ $$s(x) : = +\infty. \chi_X = +\infty,\ \ x \in X.$$

Then how do I find out $$\int s\ d\mu = \int_X +\infty\ d\mu = +\infty . \mu(X) = +\infty . 0$$

But what is $+\infty.0$? Isn't it an indeterminant form?

Comment: The convention in measure theory is that $\infty\times0=0$.

Comment: @Angina Seng can you give some reference which justifies your argument?

Comment: If it were anything other that $0$, then you wouldn't have that almost-everywhere equal functions have the same integral.

Comment: @Gae.S, X is the entire space. Then how would you take $x \notin X$?

Answer (score 1):

The generally accepted definition for a simple function is: a measurable function $g$ is simple if and only if it image is finite and is contained in $\mathbb{R}$, thus the function defined by $s:=\infty \mathbf{1}_{X}$ is not simple because $\infty\notin \mathbb{R}$.

The integral of $s$ is zero, and this follows directly from the definition of the integral of Lebesgue, that is, if $f$ is a non-negative $\mu$-measurable function then

$$
\int_{X} f \mathop{}\!d \mu :=\sup\left\{\int_{X}g \mathop{}\!d \mu : g \text{ is simple and }g\leqslant f\right\}
$$

Now: let $g:=\sum_{k=1}^n c_k \mathbf{1}_{A_k}$ where each $c_k\in \mathbb{R}$ and each $A_k$ is $\mu$-measurable, then $g$ is simple and it integral (respect to $\mu$) is defined by $\sum_{k=1}^n c_k \mu(A_k)$.

Therefore it follows that the integral of any simple function in a set of measure zero is zero, because

$$
\int_{X}g \mathop{}\!d \mu := \int \mathbf{1}_{X}g \mathop{}\!d \mu = \int\left(\sum_{k=1}^n c_k \mathbf{1}_{A_k}\mathbf{1}_{X}\right) \mathop{}\!d \mu\\
=\int \left(\sum_{k=1}^n c_k \mathbf{1}_{A_k \cap X}\right) \mathop{}\!d \mu = \sum_{k=1}^n c_k \mu(A_k \cap X)=0
$$

because $\mu(A_k \cap X)=0$ for each $k$. Therefore $\int_X s \mathop{}\!d \mu =0$.

---

However, if you have a different definition of simple function that includes the value $\infty$ for the $c_k$, then the result cannot be proved, it must be assumed as an axiom or convention in the context of Lebesgue integration theory.

Comment: I am defining a simple function over the extended real line $\Bbb R^*$; not over $\Bbb R.$ By the way, I think you mean $\int_X g\ d\mu = 0.$

Comment: Go through the lectures by Inder K. Rana about **Measure and Integration** available for free to watch in youtube. There you find this kind of weird definition. Don't think that I make this definition for my own purpose. It was the person who defined it in that way.

Answer (score 0):

The integral of every simple function is $0$, and this is why the sup of them, which is the integral you wanted, is $0$.

Comment: I mean, you could make the argument that $\infty\times \chi_X$ is simple, since its range is finite (it's the set $\{0,\infty\}$).